# Add one to firstDigit - Haskell

Tags: haskell

Two functions `digits` and `firstDigit` are defined as follows:

```
digits :: String -> String
digits st = [ ch | ch <- st , isDigit ch ]

firstDigit :: String -> Char
firstDigit st
 = case (digits st) of
     []     -> '\0'
     (x:_)  -> x
```

However, how would I go about defining a function that adds one to this `firstDigit` and then returns the result.

P

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow can be for homework help, not homework answering.

Comment: firstDigitPlusOne :: String -> Char
firstDigitPlusOne st
 = case (digits st) of
     []     -> '\0'
     (x:_)  -> x+1

Comment: There's a slight problem with the problem statement: what should `firstDigitPlusOne "99"` return? The integer `10`? The `String` `"10"`? Or the character `'10'` (which doesn't exist!) or maybe even `'A'`? And whatever you choose, you're going to run into problems (eventually) when there are no digits to increase at all...

Comment: Bad programmer! Bad! Use `Maybe Char` in `firstDigit`. The approach you are using is bound to be annoying, since one has to remember that it might return '\0'...

Comment: @monadic Oh come on, overloading the return value, such as returning NULL, isn't that bad.  One sec, server crashed... ok anyway, returning NULL really isn't that big a deal - people can figure this stuff out.  It won't cause any real issues. ;-)

Comment: ....assuming "isn't that big a deal...it won't cause any real issues"

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `digitToInt`, defined in `Data.Char`.

Comment: how would I go about applying it to the function defined above?

Comment: Your function returns Char and digitToInt accepts Char as its input (Char -> Int) so what else would you wish ?